# To identify what are the channels that increase more than 10% against the data of last week

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I have a large data frame across different timestamps. Here is my attempt:

```
all_data = []
for ws in wb.worksheets():
  rows=ws.get_all_values()
  df_all_data=pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows[1:],columns=rows[0])
  all_data.append(df_all_data)

data = pd.concat(all_data)
   

 
#Change data type
data['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Week']).year
data['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Week']).month
data['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Week']).dt.date
data['Application'] = data['Application'].astype('str')
data['Function'] = data['Function'].astype('str')
data['Service'] = data['Service'].astype('str')
data['Channel'] = data['Channel'].astype('str')
data['Times of alarms'] = data['Times of alarms'].astype('int')

#Compare Channel values over weeks

subchannel_df = data.pivot_table('Times of alarms', index = 'Week', columns='Channel', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
subchannel_df = subchannel_df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

[The data frame I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03MTH.png)

What I hope to achieve:

1. add a percentage row (the last row vs the second last row) at the end of the data frame, excluding situations as such: divide by zero and negative percentage
2. show those channels which increase more than 10% as compared against last week.

I have been trying different methods to achieve those for days. However, I would not manage to do it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the shift function as an equivalent to Lag window function in SQL to return last week's value and then perform the calculations in row level. To avoid dividing by zero you can use numpy where function that is equivalent to CASE WHEN in SQL. Let's say your column value on which you perform the calculations named: "X"

```
subchannel_df["XLag"] = subchannel_df["X"].shift(periods=1).fillna(0).astype('int')
subchannel_df["ChangePercentage"] = np.where(subchannel_df["XLag"] == 0, 0, (subchannel_df["X"]-subchannel_df["XLag"])/subchannel_df["XLag"])
subchannel_df["ChangePercentage"] = (subchannel_df["ChangePercentage"]*100).round().astype("int")
subchannel_df[subchannel_df["ChangePercentage"]>10]
```

Output:

```
Channel     X   XLag  ChangePercentage
Week            
2020-06-12  12  5     140
2020-11-15  15  10    50
2020-11-22  20  15    33
2020-12-13  27  16    69
2020-12-20  100 27    270
```

Comment: I just want to calculate the increase in the past week (The last row vs the second last row). Why would you use shift function in this case? is it possible to add percentage after the last week index in this case? Thank you.

Comment: oh i got it. That was for a demonstration purpose.

Comment: The solution I proposed gives you the ability to observe these changes on every row level and not only the last ones. You can determine trend across time. 
If it answers your question, I'll appreciate accepting it as an answer.
@user14483865